# Kubectl patch returning "not patched"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, containers, kubectl

I am running kubectl version 1.7

I am trying to add an init container to my deployment via `kubectl patch` but no matter how I try it it simply returns "not patched".

`kubectl patch deployment my-deployment --patch "$(cat ./init-patch.yaml)"`
**deployment "my-deployment" not patched**

`spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: my-mount-init
          image: "my-image"
          command:
            - "sh"
            - "-c"
            - "mkdir /mnt/data && chmod -R a+rwx /mnt/data"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: "my-volume"
              mountPath: "/mnt/data"
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 0
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: "0.2"
              memory: "256Mi"
            requests:
              cpu: "0.1"
              memory: "128Mi"`

This is to allow a custom linux user rights to read and write to the volume instead of needing to be the root user.

Wish there was a better response as to why it is not being patched..

Comment: Can you please run the patch command with a flag: `--v=7`

Comment: Do you get any errors if you adjust your deployment.yaml manually and then run < kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml > ?

Answer (score 2):

Kubectl is not idempotent. If the element to be patched already contains the patch, kubectl patch fails.

The solution can be read in Natim's comment, but it took me a while to realise that was indeed my problem.

Comment: I had this issue with kubectl version 1.10.5. A newer version changed that behavior. An update to 1.15.3 made the patch return an error code 0 even if the patch already has been applied before. In such a case stdout prints: "patched (no change)"